# Android Tab Activity

Tags: android

1. I have 4 tabs in activity group.
2. In Each tab(Separate Activity group) there are around 5 activities and I'm switching   between the activities without any problem.
3. My problem is with the device Emulator device back button.
4. Suppose I'm on 4th tab when application launches. and when I click on back button I'm showing dialog box to exit app. and it showing me the dialog box as well. But when I move to some other activities in 4th tab I'm not able to maintain the stack of activities and whenever I press back button then my app is minimizing.
   this problem is occurring in all tabs.

Answer (score 0):

So you're only overriding the back button in the main activity with the tabs?

Perhaps you need to override the back button in each of the tab's activities too (to make sure that it goes backwards to the right activity or to see if it is closing the app).

Comment: HI Thanks for the answer. Override means OnBackKeyPressed(){} on every activity i can start the previous intent and finish the currnt activity?

Comment: Yes, OnBackKeyPressed.  So if you were in a sub-activity, pressing back could cause an intent to fire to make it go back to what you consider to be the previous activity (if the normal stack of activities isn't working correctly for you).